# Adding button for each elements of list in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble putting a button into the element of the list based on Thymeleaf. I would like to have a button next to element of the list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layout.html}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<section layout:fragment="" content="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <a th:href="@{/archives}">archiwum zadań</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <a th:href="@{/add}">dodawanie zadania</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li th:each="task: ${tasks}"
            th:text="|${task.getId()} ${task.getName()} ${task.getCategory().getDescription()} ${task.isFinished()}|">
            <input type="submit" value="Done">
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf will replace any pre-existing tag content with whatever is generated by the `th:text` expression.

In your case that pre-existing content is your `<input>` element - which is why the buttons are not displayed.

One way to avoid this is to place your `th:text` into a span inside the `<li>`:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="task: ${tasks}">
        <span th:text="|${task.id} ${task.name} ... |"></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Done">
    </li>
</ul>
```

(I removed a couple of your fields from my example, for brevity).

Note also in my case, I have changed `${task.getId}` to `${task.id}`. As long as you have appropriately named getters (as per the JavaBeans naming convention) you can use the field name - and Thymeleaf will find the correct getter to call.